# redraw funnel chart in highchart when a segment is removed?

Tags: charts, highcharts

Is there a way funnel chart will redraw like pie chart does, when a segment is removed?

Similar to this question [redraw pie chart in highchart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514025/redraw-pie-chart-in-highchart)

http://jsfiddle.net/2Me2z/

```
 $(function () {
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'pie'
            },

            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    showInLegend: true
                }
            },

            legend: {
                enabled: true
            },

            series: [{
                data: [20, 30, 30, 20]        
            }]
        });

        // button handler
        $('#button').click(function() {
            var series = chart.series[0];
            if (series.data.length) {
                chart.series[0].data[0].remove(); 
            }
        });
    });
```

So click on any slice in legend will cause the chart to redraw and the remaining slices will take up 100%

Wonder if the same thing can be done for a funnel chart

http://jsfiddle.net/YUL5c/2/

```
  $(function () {
        var chart;

        $(document).ready(function () {

            // Build the chart
            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                     type: 'funnel',
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2010'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        allowPointSelect: true,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        showInLegend: true
                    }
                },
                series: [{

                    name: 'Browser share',
                    data: [
                        ['Firefox',   45.0],
                        ['IE',       26.8],
                        {
                            name: 'Chrome',
                            y: 12.8,
                            sliced: true,
                            selected: true
                        },
                        ['Safari',    8.5],
                        ['Opera',     6.2],
                        ['Others',   0.01]
                    ]
                }]
            });
        });

    });


Currently the segment just disaapear. But the chart does not redraw
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this animation is not supported, but I advice to post your request on the [uservoice website](http://highcharts.uservoice.com)

Answer (score 0):

point.visible flag is ignored in funnel code. 
If adding the check back to the drawing logic things just work magically. Even for the animation.
Not sure if it is a bug or ignored by intention